# read and rename keys json file when a new file is added to a directory

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python script which is watching a folder using inotify, and when a new json file is added I would like the file to be opened, and the keys of the json file to be renamed as indicated below (e.g. a - aa, b -- bb). The value in each key value pair should remain the same.

The below is an extract of the script in which I am trying to achieve this task.

When run I get the error

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'

I am also pretty sure this is not the best or most efficient way to do this, so open to suggestions...

```
import glob


names_key = { 'a' : 'aa' ,
              'b' : 'bb',
              'c' : 'cc',
              'd' : 'dd',
              'e' : 'ee',
              'f' : 'ff',
              'g' : 'gg',
              'h' : 'hh'
              }

destinationFolder = "inspect"
all_files = glob.glob('inspect/*.json')

def rename_json():
    for row in all_files:
        for k, v in names_key.items():
            for old_name in row:
                if k == old_name:
                    row[v] = row.pop(old_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rename_json()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn  the JSON from your JSON file into a dict with json.loads(your_entire_json_file_as_a_string)

Then you can  directly key into your json to change the appropriate keys.

#### For Example:

```
import json

def get_json_file_as_string(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as json_file:
        return json_file.read().replace('\n', '')

file_path = changed_json_file_path
names_key = { 'a' : 'aa' , 'b' : 'bb', }
json_dict = json.loads(get_json_file_as_string(changed_json_file_path))
json_dict = {'aa':1, 'bb':2}

for new_key, old_key in names_key.items():
     if old_key in  json_dict:
          json_dict[new_key] = json_dict[old_key]
          json_dict.pop(old_key)

print(json_dict)
```

#### Edit

This depends on the structure of the data in your JSON file. But if it's just a simple list of name value pairs this will work nicely

Comment: thanks @Arran how would iI load the file into all_files and feed into the dictionary thanks

Comment: @Bat are you trying to edit all of the json files or just one file? My impression was that you are just editing the file that has changed?

Comment: it would be just one file. The full script sits watching a directory and when a new json files appears, it should open the file and rename the headers. The name of the file will change each time it appears in the directory, so no sure how to call it in the json_dict. Maybe I shouldnt be using glob ?

Comment: @bat **glob** will give you a list of all of the json files in the inspect folder. I have updated the code to add the `get_json_file_as_string` method. simply pass in the path of the json file that   has been updated and  this method return a string object containing the json. Then the code should work

Comment: thanks arran looks like a good solution. Thank you for your help !